# need help MD5sum hash

Tags: command-line, text-processing, md5sum, hash

Guys I have a question I have a txt file full of names and I want to hash to md5sum for all the names in the txt at once with one by command Can you help with that and thanks in advance.

Thank you very much for your help, but there is a problem when I make the command line convert the texts to the normal md5 encoder, but I want it in md5sum format because when I encode this name, for example, Jeremy Bowers with this command line

echo "Jeremy Bowers" | $(command -v md5sum || command -v md5)

encodes the name like this

(32cacbec4b918e2fd130fd68cf818ae5)

but with that command I used this

> while read -r line; do printf %s "$line" | md5sum | cut -f1 -d' ';
> done < {filename} > {output filename}

it shows me all the names normal md5 encoding like this

(4aa63484b44863afe33675ffa7fea0e5)

It works for me but it shows me all the texts in the normal md5 encoding way and not md5sum so I want the same text command that does the same as the one I have this

> echo "Jeremy Bowers" | $(command -v md5sum || command -v md5)

but I want it to encode all the names inside the text line by line
and thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want to produce a hash of the entire file, or hash each individual name seperatley?

Comment: If you think one of the answers is correct, please accept the answer by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ and turn it green ✅.

Comment: I haven't solved my problem yet and you can now read more about what I mean, and if it's difficult and you don't understand what I mean well, we can talk on Discord and show you what I mean

Comment: See this [question and answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65499/difference-between-os-x-md5-and-gnu-md5sum) to understand why you get a different result when you use `echo "Jeremy Bowers" | mdsum` versus `while read -r line; do printf %s "$line" | md5sum | cut -f1 -d' '; done < {filename} > {output filename}`. The difference is the **newline** char added at the end by `echo`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification but I was wondering how I can do the command line, while read -r line; do printf %s "$line" | md5sum | cut -f1 -d' '; done < {filename} > {output filename} with that newline to get my same results and thanks in advance

Comment: In this question answer site, the comments are not suitable for discussions. You may edit your question or ask a new question highlighting the differences between the two commands and adding a link to this question in your new question.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to hash the entire file, you simply run

```
md5um {filename}
```

If the names are separated by new lines, you could hash each new line in the file using the following command

```
while read -r line; do printf %s "$line" | md5sum | cut -f1 -d' '; done < {filename}
```

This loops through each new line, printing to the terminal the hash of each line.

If you then want it to either write these hashes to a new file, or over-write the already existing file, you add `> {filename}`

Making this:

```
while read -r line; do printf %s "$line" | md5sum | cut -f1 -d' '; done < {filename} > {output filename}
```

In all of the above examples, you will need to replace `{filename}` with the path to the file you want to hash, and replace `{output filenames}` with the path to where you want the hashes to be outputed

Comment: YOOO bro
  I love youu bro thanks a looot

Answer (score 1):

With perl:

```
perl -MDigest::MD5=md5_hex -lne 'print md5_hex($_)' file.txt
```